# Double installation of apk

Tags: android, eclipse, sdk

I have an app that i am working on. but when i run it through the eclipse avd... It shows two icons in the app screen. any ideas what is going on?

Also I used the apk to install on my phone and i also saw two installation of the same app on my phone.

Comment: Need more info. What's in the manifest? Do you have two LAUNCHER intents? Did you ever rename the class/package name during the development process?

Answer (score 2):

you have to set a one Launcher activity in your manifest. that is

you set it as:

```
<activity android:name=".Activity1" android:label="@string/appname">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".Activity2" android:label="@string/appname">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

you have to put the `<category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />` instead of `<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />` for your the activity you dont want to launch.

Comment: if this isn't the case then he must have renamed the package